# Reactjs npm start causes error ELIFECYCLE/3221225477

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just installed React through the command `npm init react-app client` and tried to start it through `npm start`, but got the following error.
But some details before that, I've installed React globally through `npm install -g create-react-app` and I am using VS Code.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~prestart: client@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: client@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Projeto\client\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\leopl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\;C:\Users\leopl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\;C:\Users\leopl\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\leopl\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\leopl\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Projeto\client
10 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle client@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid client@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Projeto\client
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error client@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the client@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried:

1. Clean cache

   - `npm cache clean --force`
   - delete node_modules folder
   - delete package-lock.json file
   - `npm install`
2. Just deleted everything

   - Delete everything in the folder
   - Install again with `npm init react-app client` (but I've tried `create-react-app client` as well)
3. Uninstall React and install again

   - Delete everything in the folder
   - `npm -g uninstall create-react-app --save`
   - Install everything again
4. Install 2 times (I saw that this worked for one person, so I tried it too)

   - `npm init react-app client`
   - `npm install`

One additional information, but that may be important, I can not run `react-scripts start`. I can not describe exactly what is the error in VS Code because it is in PT-BR, but it says the term `react-scripts` was not recognized and had a `CommandNotFoundException` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing solved this problem, I was using the latest version of Node.js (Latest - 12.0.0), I uninstalled it and installed the 10.15.3 LTS version, it is now normal. I did not even need to reinstall React again.

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is install `create-react-app` globally by using this command

`npm install -g create-react-app`.

After that, you can use create-react-app CLI (command line interface) like below:

`create-react-app <your_app_name>`

With npm version higher than 5.2, here is the shortcut:

`npx create-react-app <your_app_name>`

Hope this help.

Comment: I did it, the `create-react-app` is installed.